# pselect blocks even though data is available for read on socket

Tags: c++, sockets, posix

I'm experiencing an intermittent delay when reading from a POSIX socket (RHEL6 x86_64 C++ icpc). My code is designed such that a user can provide an absolute timespec deadline (vs. a relative timeout) to be used across multiple calls to recv. I call pselect to make sure that data is available for reading before attempting to call recv.

This typically works as expected (will wait for data but not exceed deadline, introducing no noticeable delay if data is available to recv). However, I have a user that can periodically (~50% of the time) get his application into a state where the select blocks for ~400-500 ms even though data is available on the socket. If I watch /proc/net/tcp, I can see that data is available in the RX queue and I can see the application slowly reading the data off the queue. If I skip the call to pselect and just call recv, the behavior is similar (but less delay overall indicating recv is also blocking unnecessarily). When the application gets into this state it stays this way (experiences consistent delay with each pselect/recv).

I spent several hours poking around here and on other sites. This is the closest similar issue I could find, but there was no resolution...

http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=7458

Has anyone run into this sort of behavior before? I'm at a loss for what to do. I've instrumented the code to validate that this is where the delay is happening. (Edit: We actually just validated that the entire method below was slow, not any particular system call.) It seems like a kernel/OS issue but I'm not sure where to look. Here's the code...

```
// protected
bool
Message::wait(int socket, const timespec & deadline) {

    // Bail if deadline not provided
    if (deadline.tv_sec == 0 && deadline.tv_nsec == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // Make sure we haven't already exceeded deadline
    timespec currentTime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &currentTime);
    if (VirtualClock::cmptime(currentTime, deadline) >= 0) {
        LOG_WARNING("Timed out waiting to receive data");
        m_timedOut = true;
        return false;
    }

    // Calculate receive timeout
    timespec timeout;
    memset(&timeout, 0, sizeof(timeout));
    timeout.tv_nsec = VirtualClock::nsecs(currentTime, deadline);
    VirtualClock::fixtime(timeout);

    // Wait for data
    fd_set descSet;
    FD_ZERO(&descSet);
    FD_SET(socket, &descSet);
    int result = pselect(socket + 1, &descSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL);
    if (result == -1) {
        m_error = errno;
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to wait for data: %d, %s",
                m_error, strerror(m_error));
        return false;
    } else if (result == 0 || !FD_ISSET(socket, &descSet)) {
        LOG_WARNING("Timed out waiting to receive data");
        m_timedOut = true;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

VirtualClock is a time-related utility class just used here to compare/fix-up timespecs (i.e. not introducing any delays). I'd appreciate any insight on this behavior.

Comment: Is the socket `O_NONBLOCK`?

Comment: No, it's blocking. I thought that select would work the same either way though? It should return immediately when there is data available to read, regardless of whether or not the socket is blocking, shouldn't it? I was considering trying setting the socket to non-blocking, but it didn't seem like it would make a difference based on what I've read. Also, it bugs me that sometimes this happens and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I think you're right, it shouldn't make a difference.  Although, it might confirm that the kernel is blocking the socket for some reason.  If it's happening sporadically, I guess profiling isn't practical?  Maybe it's something specific to the payload?

Comment: This code is in a library that I wrote which is being used by another developer. They did some basic profiling (via valgrind and tracing) to identify where the blocking is occurring. Good idea about the payload but I don't think it's the case here. The messages being processed consist of headers and a body and the issue is observed when processing the headers which happen to be the same each time.

Comment: I can think of a few things that might cause the delays, but honestly without digging into the kernel traces they would more or less be guesses.  I don't know if you're already using [ftrace](https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/), but it could help to at least narrow the cause.  You might want to file a bug report with redhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact not a problem with any system call. We used strace to diagnose and were seeing tons of calls to clock_gettime. Another (third) review of the calling code revealed a programming error resulting in the called code having a reference to corrupt stack data. This was facilitated by a flawed API design on my part resulting in corruption of the deadline.

I was allowing the user to pass in a reference to a ServerConfig class containing configuration (including data related to the deadline). My Server class was saving the reference instead of copying the object. The user created an instance of my Server class on the heap, passed in a reference a ServerConfig on the stack (in a method) resulting in non-deterministic garbage in the configuration when the method exited and the ServerConfig went out of scope. This is older code and I've since prevented this sort of thing from happening in other places after being burned but this one slipped through.

So lessons learned for me are: be careful with writing APIs that hang on to user-provided references, rethink premature optimization (the whole reason I was hanging onto a reference instead of just doing a copy), and look for stack corruption when you see non-deterministic behavior like this (something that I check for when I suspect builds are jacked up but didn't suspect this time). Also, strace is a great tool...I've seen others use it but now I'm comfortable using it myself.

Thanks for the comments and sorry for the false alarm.